# Javascript - Questions about performance

Tags: javascript, html

I have some questions about Javascript.
Most of my website's pages use js. For better performance, what should i do ? : 
Write all of my js code in one file and link it with my pages ? Or one js file per page ?

Is it a bad manner that i never mix js into my html ? I like to have separate things (html, css, js)

Thank you.

Comment: Yeah I would suggest keeping inline script at a minimal, do as much as you can with external JavaScript files. If you can split up the JavaScript to page-specific files, do so. Keep a common set of JS files for scripts that you use throughout the site.

Comment: This question is too open ended. Are you talking about load speed? Code performance?

Comment: I'm asking about load speed.
You all guys are right, thnx for your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For maintainability**

Keep separate pages while developing the app, so that any one can make out which feature has been coded where.

**For performance**

Before deploying it for production, [minify](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/javascript-minifying-tools/) your js and css files so that there are less network calls to download those files.

> Is it a bad manner that i never mix js into my html ?

No, having non-intrusive js is both good for readability and it is good for performance too since it gives you a chance to minify the js files. You can't minify inline js.

Comment: It is far more prudent to use minified JS for UAT, otherwise you are putting extreme faith in your minifier.

Comment: @RobG yes, after minifying code has to be tested for regression and UAT (preferrably in an automated manner for code coverage) before giving it to production.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is writing a relatively big website in ASP.MVC .
I did not write all the javascript code in one file because that would have been difficult to manage. I made a folder that included multiple javascript files, each having its own purpose. 
If the javascript is more than say 10 lines of code, and you can put it outside the html file, i would advise so, because it is faster to look at .

Comment: That is fine for development, but files should be concatenated into a smaller number of files for production.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to just have one .js file for all pages, but it is better for readability if you have multiple files.
Mixing javascript into HTML can be useful but it depends on your needs.